# Send props to react router component from parent layout component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a layout component called `Main` which sends user prop to its children component using `React.cloneElement(children, { user: 'First Name'})`, but unable to pass that user prop to Route component.

> index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./Main.jsx";
import Home from "./Home.jsx";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Main>
      <Route
        path="/"
        render={props => {
          return <Home {...props} />;
        }}
      />
    </Main>
  </Router>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

> Main.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default props => {
  return <div>{React.cloneElement(props.children, { user: "Username" })}</div>;
};
```

> Home.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default props => {
  const { user } = props;
  return <div>User - {user}</div>;
};
```

But unable to get `user` prop in `Home` component. If I do not use `Route` then it gets passed to `Home`.

When I do this, then `Home` receives `user` prop.

```
<Main>
   <Home />
</Main>
```

How can I get `user` prop and send it to component rendered by `Route`?

Codesandox link of the scenario - https://codesandbox.io/s/kmyrj0zr8o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to wrap `Route` into own component. The idea is to catch props and pass it manually to `Route`'s `render`.

Here is modified source: https://codesandbox.io/s/zx508v60yl

Wrapping `Route` (`MyRoute.jsx`)

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default class MyRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var { Component, path, exact, passedProps } = this.props;
        return (
            <Route
                path={path}
                exact={exact}
                render={props => <Component {...props} {...passedProps} />}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Modifying `Main.jsx`

```
import React from "react";

export default props => {
    return (
        <div>
            {React.cloneElement(props.children, {
                passedProps: {
                    user: "Username"
                }
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Then changing `Route` to `MyRoute` in `index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./Main.jsx";
import Home from "./Home.jsx";
import MyRoute from "./MyRoute.jsx";

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Main>
            <MyRoute path="/" Component={Home} />
        </Main>
    </Router>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to pass props to the router component, you need to use the render prop to do that, but since `React.cloneElement` will actually just pass the props to the `Route` component, you can write a wrapper around `Route`, something like

```
const RouteWrapper = ({render, exact, strict, path, ...rest}) => {
     return (
          <Route 
              exact={exact}
              strict={strict}
              path={path}
              render={(function(routerProps) => { 
                    return render(...routerProps, ...rest)
              })()}
          />
     )
}
```

Which you can now use like

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Main>
      <RouteWrapper
        path="/"
        render={props => {
          return <Home {...props} />;
        }}
      />
    </Main>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Thanks shubham. It has a few problems in the RouteWrapper component. First syntax if incorrect and second passing props to render function. Updated code
const RouteWrapper = ({ render, exact, strict, path, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      exact={exact}
      strict={strict}
      path={path}
      render={routerProps => {
        return render({ ...rest, ...routerProps });
      }}
    />
  );
};

See the demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/wop65zooq8